# I'm trying to remove extra lines between the texts using preg_replace but it is not working as expected

Tags: php, regex

*I'm trying to remove extra lines between the texts and here is what I  tried:*

```
<?php
echo preg_replace("/^\s+/", "\n", $_POST["description"]);
```

*The input:*

[image]

*The output:*

[image]

*I tried the same regular expression on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/W1ejAl/1) and here is the result:*

[image]

*As you can see nothing changed when I executed the regular expression using PHP, But it is working as what I want when using the regex101 website.*

*The current PHP version is 7.4.28.*

*Did I miss something?*

Comment: You need to use `MULTILINE` mode e.g. `preg_replace("/^\s+/m", "\n", $_POST["description"]);` but that will still be not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `preg_replace` code that would not require `m` mode:

```bash
echo preg_replace('/(?:\h*\R){2,}/', "\n", $_POST["description"]);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q1ymXM/1)

Here `(?:\h*\R){2,}` has a non-capture group that will match 0 or more horizontal whitespaces followed by any kind of line break. This non-capture group is repeated 2 or more times.

Please note that it will also remove trailing and leading whitespaces in addition to stripping multiple line breaks into one.

---

Alternatively using your own approach it would be:

```php
echo preg_replace('/^\s+/m', "\n", $_POST["description"]);
```

Note that would require `m` or `MULTILINE` mode.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q1ymXM/3)

Comment: Change `""` to `"\n"`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that normally `^\s+` refers to the very start of the string, and not to the start of each line, unless you run the regex in multiline mode.  But I think you really want this logic instead:

```php
echo preg_replace("/\n{2,}/", "\n", $_POST["description"]);
```

This just replaces 2 or more newlines with a single newline.

Comment: It is not working, [Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYm3I.png)